# How To create "coverflow" Swiper using swiper JS

Tags: html, css, slider, carousel, swiper.js

I am facing an issue with "coverflow" Swiper slider. I want to show only 3 images at a time in the slider but I'm unable to achieve that.

expected output video:
https://gofile.io/d/pl2AQI

Here is screenshot how it should be:

[image]

```js
var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
  effect: 'coverflow',
  loop: true,
  centeredSlides: true,
  slidesPerView: 3,
  initialSlide: 1,
  keyboardControl: true,
  mousewheelControl: true,
  lazyLoading: true,
  centeredSlides: true,
  preventClicks: false,
  preventClicksPropagation: false,
  lazyLoadingInPrevNext: true,
  coverflow: {
    rotate: 0,
    stretch: 150,
    depth: 200,
    modifier: 1,
    slideShadows: false,
  },
});
```

```css
.swiper-pagination-bullet {
  border: 1px solid #1da1f2;
}

.swiper-pagination-bullet-active {
  background: #1da1f2
}

img:not([draggable]),
embed,
object,
video {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.swiper-container {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 1
}

.swiper-container-no-flexbox .swiper-slide {
  float: left
}

.swiper-container-vertical>.swiper-wrapper {
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column
}

.swiper-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform;
  transition-property: -webkit-transform;
  transition-property: transform;
  transition-property: transform, -webkit-transform;
  box-sizing: content-box
}

.swiper-container-android .swiper-slide,
.swiper-wrapper {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0)
}

.swiper-container-multirow>.swiper-wrapper {
  -webkit-box-lines: multiple;
  -moz-box-lines: multiple;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap
}

.swiper-container-free-mode>.swiper-wrapper {
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
  transition-timing-function: ease-out;
  margin: 0 auto
}

.swiper-slide {
  -webkit-flex-shrink: 0;
  -ms-flex: 0 0 auto;
  -ms-flex-negative: 0;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative
}

.swiper-container-autoheight,
.swiper-container-autoheight .swiper-slide {
  height: auto
}

.swiper-container-autoheight .swiper-wrapper {
  -webkit-box-align: start;
  -ms-flex-align: start;
  align-items: flex-start;
  -webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform, height;
  -webkit-transition-property: height, -webkit-transform;
  transition-property: height, -webkit-transform;
  transition-property: transform, height;
  transition-property: transform, height, -webkit-transform
}

.swiper-container .swiper-notification {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: -1000
}

.swiper-wp8-horizontal {
  -ms-touch-action: pan-y;
  touch-action: pan-y
}

.swiper-wp8-vertical {
  -ms-touch-action: pan-x;
  touch-action: pan-x
}

.swiper-button-next,
.swiper-button-prev {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: 27px;
  height: 44px;
  margin-top: -22px;
  z-index: 10;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-size: 27px 44px;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.swiper-button-next.swiper-button-disabled,
.swiper-button-prev.swiper-button-disabled {
  opacity: .35;
  cursor: auto;
  pointer-events: none
}

.swiper-button-prev,
.swiper-container-rtl .swiper-button-next {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,%3Csvg%20xmlns%3D'http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg'%20viewBox%3D'0%200%2027%2044'%3E%3Cpath%20d%3D'M0%2C22L22%2C0l2.1%2C2.1L4.2%2C22l19.9%2C19.9L22%2C44L0%2C22L0%2C22L0%2C22z'%20fill%3D'%23007aff'%2F%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E");
  left: 10px;
  right: auto
}

.swiper-button-prev.swiper-button-black,
.swiper-container-rtl .swiper-button-next.swiper-button-black {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,%3Csvg%20xmlns%3D'http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg'%20viewBox%3D'0%200%2027%2044'%3E%3Cpath%20d%3D'M0%2C22L22%2C0l2.1%2C2.1L4.2%2C22l19.9%2C19.9L22%2C44L0%2C22L0%2C22L0%2C22z'%20fill%3D'%23000000'%2F%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E")
}

.swiper-button-prev.swiper-button-white,
.swiper-container-rtl .swiper-button-next.swiper-button-white {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,%3Csvg%20xmlns%3D'http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg'%20viewBox%3D'0%200%2027%2044'%3E%3Cpath%20d%3D'M0%2C22L22%2C0l2.1%2C2.1L4.2%2C22l19.9%2C19.9L22%2C44L0%2C22L0%2C22L0%2C22z'%20fill%3D'%23ffffff'%2F%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E")
}

.swiper-button-next,
.swiper-container-rtl .swiper-button-prev {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,%3Csvg%20xmlns%3D'http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg'%20viewBox%3D'0%200%2027%2044'%3E%3Cpath%20d%3D'M27%2C22L27%2C22L5%2C44l-2.1-2.1L22.8%2C22L2.9%2C2.1L5%2C0L27%2C22L27%2C22z'%20fill%3D'%23007aff'%2F%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E");
  right: 10px;
  left: auto
}

.swiper-button-next.swiper-button-black,
.swiper-container-rtl .swiper-button-prev.swiper-button-black {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,%3Csvg%20xmlns%3D'http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg'%20viewBox%3D'0%200%2027%2044'%3E%3Cpath%20d%3D'M27%2C22L27%2C22L5%2C44l-2.1-2.1L22.8%2C22L2.9%2C2.1L5%2C0L27%2C22L27%2C22z'%20fill%3D'%23000000'%2F%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E")
}

.swiper-button-next.swiper-button-white,
.swiper-container-rtl .swiper-button-prev.swiper-button-white {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,%3Csvg%20xmlns%3D'http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg'%20viewBox%3D'0%200%2027%2044'%3E%3Cpath%20d%3D'M27%2C22L27%2C22L5%2C44l-2.1-2.1L22.8%2C22L2.9%2C2.1L5%2C0L27%2C22L27%2C22z'%20fill%3D'%23ffffff'%2F%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E")
}

.swiper-pagination {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-transition: .3s;
  transition: .3s;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  z-index: 10
}

.swiper-pagination.swiper-pagination-hidden {
  opacity: 0
}

.swiper-container-horizontal>.swiper-pagination-bullets,
.swiper-pagination-custom,
.swiper-pagination-fraction {
  bottom: 10px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%
}

.swiper-pagination-bullet {
  width: 8px;
  height: 8px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background: #000;
  opacity: .2
}

button.swiper-pagination-bullet {
  border: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-shadow: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  -ms-appearance: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none
}

.swiper-pagination-clickable .swiper-pagination-bullet {
  cursor: pointer
}

.swiper-pagination-white .swiper-pagination-bullet {
  background: #fff
}

.swiper-pagination-bullet-active {
  opacity: 1;
  background: #007aff
}

.swiper-pagination-white .swiper-pagination-bullet-active {
  background: #fff
}

.swiper-pagination-black .swiper-pagination-bullet-active {
  background: #000
}

.swiper-container-vertical>.swiper-pagination-bullets {
  right: 10px;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -50%, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, -50%, 0)
}

.swiper-container-vertical>.swiper-pagination-bullets .swiper-pagination-bullet {
  margin: 5px 0;
  display: block
}

.swiper-container-horizontal>.swiper-pagination-bullets .swiper-pagination-bullet {
  margin: 0 5px
}

.swiper-pagination-progress {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .25);
  position: absolute
}

.swiper-pagination-progress .swiper-pagination-progressbar {
  background: #007aff;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-transform: scale(0);
  transform: scale(0);
  -webkit-transform-origin: left top;
  transform-origin: left top
}

.swiper-container-rtl .swiper-pagination-progress .swiper-pagination-progressbar {
  -webkit-transform-origin: right top;
  transform-origin: right top
}

.swiper-container-horizontal>.swiper-pagination-progress {
  width: 100%;
  height: 4px;
  left: 0;
  top: 0
}

.swiper-container-vertical>.swiper-pagination-progress {
  width: 4px;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0
}

.swiper-pagination-progress.swiper-pagination-white {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .5)
}

.swiper-pagination-progress.swiper-pagination-white .swiper-pagination-progressbar {
  background: #fff
}

.swiper-pagination-progress.swiper-pagination-black .swiper-pagination-progressbar {
  background: #000
}

.swiper-container-3d {
  -webkit-perspective: 1200px;
  -o-perspective: 1200px;
  perspective: 1200px
}

.swiper-container-3d .swiper-cube-shadow,
.swiper-container-3d .swiper-slide,
.swiper-container-3d .swiper-slide-shadow-bottom,
.swiper-container-3d .swiper-slide-shadow-left,
.swiper-container-3d .swiper-slide-shadow-right,
.swiper-container-3d .swiper-slide-shadow-top,
.swiper-container-3d .swiper-wrapper {
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d
}

.swiper-container-3d .swiper-slide-shadow-bottom,
.swiper-container-3d .swiper-slide-shadow-left,
.swiper-container-3d .swiper-slide-shadow-right,
.swiper-container-3d .swiper-slide-shadow-top {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  pointer-events: none;
  z-index: 10;
}

.swiper-container-3d .swiper-slide-shadow-left {
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, from(rgba(0, 0, 0, .5)), to(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(right, rgba(0, 0, 0, .5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left, rgba(0, 0, 0, .5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0))
}

.swiper-container-3d .swiper-slide-shadow-right {
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, right top, left top, from(rgba(0, 0, 0, .5)), to(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0, 0, 0, .5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0, 0, 0, .5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0))
}

.swiper-container-3d .swiper-slide-shadow-top {
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(rgba(0, 0, 0, .5)), to(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, .5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top, rgba(0, 0, 0, .5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0))
}

.swiper-container-3d .swiper-slide-shadow-bottom {
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left bottom, left top, from(rgba(0, 0, 0, .5)), to(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, .5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, .5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0))
}

.swiper-container-coverflow .swiper-wrapper,
.swiper-container-flip .swiper-wrapper {
  -ms-perspective: 1200px
}

.swiper-container-cube,
.swiper-container-flip {
  overflow: visible
}

.swiper-container-cube .swiper-slide,
.swiper-container-flip .swiper-slide {
  pointer-events: none;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  z-index: 1
}

.swiper-container-cube .swiper-slide .swiper-slide,
.swiper-container-flip .swiper-slide .swiper-slide {
  pointer-events: none
}

.swiper-container-cube .swiper-slide-active,
.swiper-container-cube .swiper-slide-active .swiper-slide-active,
.swiper-container-flip .swiper-slide-active,
.swiper-container-flip .swiper-slide-active .swiper-slide-active {
  pointer-events: auto
}

.swiper-container-cube .swiper-slide-shadow-bottom,
.swiper-container-cube .swiper-slide-shadow-left,
.swiper-container-cube .swiper-slide-shadow-right,
.swiper-container-cube .swiper-slide-shadow-top,
.swiper-container-flip .swiper-slide-shadow-bottom,
.swiper-container-flip .swiper-slide-shadow-left,
.swiper-container-flip .swiper-slide-shadow-right,
.swiper-container-flip .swiper-slide-shadow-top {
  z-index: 0;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden
}

.swiper-container-cube .swiper-slide {
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%
}

.swiper-container-cube.swiper-container-rtl .swiper-slide {
  -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 0;
  transform-origin: 100% 0
}

.swiper-container-cube .swiper-slide-active,
.swiper-container-cube .swiper-slide-next,
.swiper-container-cube .swiper-slide-next+.swiper-slide,
.swiper-container-cube .swiper-slide-prev {
  pointer-events: auto;
  visibility: visible
}

.swiper-container-cube .swiper-cube-shadow {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #000;
  opacity: .6;
  -webkit-filter: blur(50px);
  filter: blur(50px);
  z-index: 0
}

.swiper-container-fade.swiper-container-free-mode .swiper-slide {
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
  transition-timing-function: ease-out
}

.swiper-container-fade .swiper-slide {
  pointer-events: none;
  -webkit-transition-property: opacity;
  transition-property: opacity
}

.swiper-container-fade .swiper-slide .swiper-slide {
  pointer-events: none
}

.swiper-container-fade .swiper-slide-active,
.swiper-container-fade .swiper-slide-active .swiper-slide-active {
  pointer-events: auto
}

.swiper-zoom-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center
}

.swiper-zoom-container>canvas,
.swiper-zoom-container>img,
.swiper-zoom-container>svg {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  -o-object-fit: contain;
  object-fit: contain
}

.swiper-scrollbar {
  border-radius: 10px;
  position: relative;
  -ms-touch-action: none;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .1)
}

.swiper-container-horizontal>.swiper-scrollbar {
  position: absolute;
  left: 1%;
  bottom: 3px;
  z-index: 50;
  height: 5px;
  width: 98%
}

.swiper-container-vertical>.swiper-scrollbar {
  position: absolute;
  right: 3px;
  top: 1%;
  z-index: 50;
  width: 5px;
  height: 98%
}

.swiper-scrollbar-drag {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  border-radius: 10px;
  left: 0;
  top: 0
}

.swiper-scrollbar-cursor-drag {
  cursor: move
}

.swiper-lazy-preloader {
  width: 42px;
  height: 42px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  margin-left: -21px;
  margin-top: -21px;
  z-index: 10;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50%;
  transform-origin: 50%;
  -webkit-animation: swiper-preloader-spin 1s steps(12, end) infinite;
  animation: swiper-preloader-spin 1s steps(12, end) infinite
}

.swiper-lazy-preloader:after {
  display: block;
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,%3Csvg%20viewBox%3D'0%200%20120%20120'%20xmlns%3D'http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg'%20xmlns%3Axlink%3D'http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2Fxlink'%3E%3Cdefs%3E%3Cline%20id%3D'l'%20x1%3D'60'%20x2%3D'60'%20y1%3D'7'%20y2%3D'27'%20stroke%3D'%236c6c6c'%20stroke-width%3D'11'%20stroke-linecap%3D'round'%2F%3E%3C%2Fdefs%3E%3Cg%3E%3Cuse%20xlink%3Ahref%3D'%23l'%20opacity%3D'.27'%2F%3E%3Cuse%20xlink%3Ahref%3D'%23l'%20opacity%3D'.27'%20transform%3D'rotate(30%2060%2C60)'%2F%3E%3Cuse%20xlink%3Ahref%3D'%23l'%20opacity%3D'.27'%20transform%3D'rotate(60%2060%2C60)'%2F%3E%3Cuse%20xlink%3Ahref%3D'%23l'%20opacity%3D'.27'%20transform%3D'rotate(90%2060%2C60)'%2F%3E%3Cuse%20xlink%3Ahref%3D'%23l'%20opacity%3D'.27'%20transform%3D'rotate(120%2060%2C60)'%2F%3E%3Cuse%20xlink%3Ahref%3D'%23l'%20opacity%3D'.27'%20transform%3D'rotate(150%2060%2C60)'%2F%3E%3Cuse%20xlink%3Ahref%3D'%23l'%20opacity%3D'.37'%20transform%3D'rotate(180%2060%2C60)'%2F%3E%3Cuse%20xlink%3Ahref%3D'%23l'%20opacity%3D'.46'%20transform%3D'rotate(210%2060%2C60)'%2F%3E%3Cuse%20xlink%3Ahref%3D'%23l'%20opacity%3D'.56'%20transform%3D'rotate(240%2060%2C60)'%2F%3E%3Cuse%20xlink%3Ahref%3D'%23l'%20opacity%3D'.66'%20transform%3D'rotate(270%2060%2C60)'%2F%3E%3Cuse%20xlink%3Ahref%3D'%23l'%20opacity%3D'.75'%20transform%3D'rotate(300%2060%2C60)'%2F%3E%3Cuse%20xlink%3Ahref%3D'%23l'%20opacity%3D'.85'%20transform%3D'rotate(330%2060%2C60)'%2F%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E");
  background-position: 50%;
  background-size: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat
}

.swiper-lazy-preloader-white:after {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,%3Csvg%20viewBox%3D'0%200%20120%20120'%20xmlns%3D'http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg'%20xmlns%3Axlink%3D'http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2Fxlink'%3E%3Cdefs%3E%3Cline%20id%3D'l'%20x1%3D'60'%20x2%3D'60'%20y1%3D'7'%20y2%3D'27'%20stroke%3D'%23fff'%20stroke-width%3D'11'%20stroke-linecap%3D'round'%2F%3E%3C%2Fdefs%3E%3Cg%3E%3Cuse%20xlink%3Ahref%3D'%23l'%20opacity%3D'.27'%2F%3E%3Cuse%20xlink%3Ahref%3D'%23l'%20opacity%3D'.27'%20transform%3D'rotate(30%2060%2C60)'%2F%3E%3Cuse%20xlink%3Ahref%3D'%23l'%20opacity%3D'.27'%20transform%3D'rotate(60%2060%2C60)'%2F%3E%3Cuse%20xlink%3Ahref%3D'%23l'%20opacity%3D'.27'%20transform%3D'rotate(90%2060%2C60)'%2F%3E%3Cuse%20xlink%3Ahref%3D'%23l'%20opacity%3D'.27'%20transform%3D'rotate(120%2060%2C60)'%2F%3E%3Cuse%20xlink%3Ahref%3D'%23l'%20opacity%3D'.27'%20transform%3D'rotate(150%2060%2C60)'%2F%3E%3Cuse%20xlink%3Ahref%3D'%23l'%20opacity%3D'.37'%20transform%3D'rotate(180%2060%2C60)'%2F%3E%3Cuse%20xlink%3Ahref%3D'%23l'%20opacity%3D'.46'%20transform%3D'rotate(210%2060%2C60)'%2F%3E%3Cuse%20xlink%3Ahref%3D'%23l'%20opacity%3D'.56'%20transform%3D'rotate(240%2060%2C60)'%2F%3E%3Cuse%20xlink%3Ahref%3D'%23l'%20opacity%3D'.66'%20transform%3D'rotate(270%2060%2C60)'%2F%3E%3Cuse%20xlink%3Ahref%3D'%23l'%20opacity%3D'.75'%20transform%3D'rotate(300%2060%2C60)'%2F%3E%3Cuse%20xlink%3Ahref%3D'%23l'%20opacity%3D'.85'%20transform%3D'rotate(330%2060%2C60)'%2F%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E")
}

@-webkit-keyframes swiper-preloader-spin {
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg)
  }
}

@keyframes swiper-preloader-spin {
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg)
  }
}

.swiper-container.one {
  padding-top: 40px;
  text-align: center;
}

.swiper-container.one .swiper-slide {
  padding: 0 43px;
}

.swiper-container {
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 60px;
}

.slider-image {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

.swiper-slide img {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 100%;
}

.swiper-slide {
  height: auto;
  padding: 0 15px;
}

.two .swiper-slide {
  width: 300px;
}

.swiper-slide img {
  box-shadow: 0 10px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}

.swiper-slide .slider-image .preview-icon {
  z-index: -1;
  width: calc(100% - 30px);
}

.swiper-slide.swiper-slide-active .slider-image:hover .preview-icon {
  opacity: 1;
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
  z-index: 1;
}

.swiper-container-horizontal>.swiper-pagination-bullets,
.swiper-pagination-custom,
.swiper-pagination-fraction {
  bottom: 0;
}

.swiper-pagination-bullet {
  background: transparent none repeat scroll 0 0;
  border: 1px solid #ee0f6f;
  border-radius: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 10px;
  opacity: 1;
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
  width: 26px;
  -webkit-transition: 0.2s;
  transition: 0.2s;
}

.swiper-pagination-bullet-active {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #ee0f6f 0%, #f89482 100%) repeat scroll 0 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) linear-gradient(to right, #ee0f6f 0%, #f89482 100%) repeat scroll 0 0;
  border: medium none;
  height: 12px;
  opacity: 1;
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
  width: 12px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.css" />

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/3.4.1/js/swiper.min.js"></script>

<div class="swiper-container two">
  <div class="swiper-wrapper">
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <div class="slider-image">
        <img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=0B_koKn2rKOkLRml1b3B6eXVqQ2s" alt="slide 1">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <div class="slider-image">
        <img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=0B_koKn2rKOkLWTdaX3J5b1VueDg" alt="slide 2">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <div class="slider-image">
        <img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=0B_koKn2rKOkLVUpEems2ZXpHYVk" alt="slide 3">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <div class="slider-image">
        <img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=0B_koKn2rKOkLNXBIcEdOUFVIWmM" alt="slide 4">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <div class="slider-image">
        <img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=0B_koKn2rKOkLWTdaX3J5b1VueDg" alt="slide 5">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <div class="slider-image">
        <img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=0B_koKn2rKOkLWTdaX3J5b1VueDg" alt="slide 5">
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Add Pagination -->
  </div>
  <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
</div>
```

Note: any custom code also welcome or any other plugin also works

Answer (score 3):

By using slidesPerView: 2 and then hidding the slides with opacity:0 except for the 3 you want to see, you can achieve what you want.

```
.swiper-slide{
opacity: 0;
}
.swiper-slide-prev,
.swiper-slide-active,
.swiper-slide-next{
opacity: 1;
}
```

And if you want to have more space between the elements, you can mess around with stretch: 150 and depth: 200.

```js
var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
  effect: 'coverflow',
  loop: true,
  centeredSlides: true,
  slidesPerView: 2,
  initialSlide: 1,
  keyboardControl: true,
  mousewheelControl: true,
  lazyLoading: true,
  centeredSlides: true,
  preventClicks: false,
  preventClicksPropagation: false,
  lazyLoadingInPrevNext: true,
  coverflow: {
    rotate: 0,
    stretch: 150,
    depth: 200,
    modifier: 1,
    slideShadows: false,
  },
});
```

```css
.swiper-pagination-bullet {
  border: 1px solid #1da1f2;
}

.swiper-pagination-bullet-active {
  background: #1da1f2
}

img:not([draggable]),
embed,
object,
video {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.swiper-container {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 1
}

.swiper-container-no-flexbox .swiper-slide {
  float: left
}

.swiper-container-vertical>.swiper-wrapper {
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column
}

.swiper-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform;
  transition-property: -webkit-transform;
  transition-property: transform;
  transition-property: transform, -webkit-transform;
  box-sizing: content-box
}

.swiper-container-android .swiper-slide,
.swiper-wrapper {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0)
}

.swiper-container-multirow>.swiper-wrapper {
  -webkit-box-lines: multiple;
  -moz-box-lines: multiple;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap
}

.swiper-container-free-mode>.swiper-wrapper {
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
  transition-timing-function: ease-out;
  margin: 0 auto
}

.swiper-slide {
  -webkit-flex-shrink: 0;
  -ms-flex: 0 0 auto;
  -ms-flex-negative: 0;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative
}

.swiper-container-autoheight,
.swiper-container-autoheight .swiper-slide {
  height: auto
}

.swiper-container-autoheight .swiper-wrapper {
  -webkit-box-align: start;
  -ms-flex-align: start;
  align-items: flex-start;
  -webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform, height;
  -webkit-transition-property: height, -webkit-transform;
  transition-property: height, -webkit-transform;
  transition-property: transform, height;
  transition-property: transform, height, -webkit-transform
}

.swiper-container .swiper-notification {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: -1000
}

.swiper-wp8-horizontal {
  -ms-touch-action: pan-y;
  touch-action: pan-y
}

.swiper-wp8-vertical {
  -ms-touch-action: pan-x;
  touch-action: pan-x
}

.swiper-button-next,
.swiper-button-prev {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: 27px;
  height: 44px;
  margin-top: -22px;
  z-index: 10;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-size: 27px 44px;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.swiper-button-next.swiper-button-disabled,
.swiper-button-prev.swiper-button-disabled {
  opacity: .35;
  cursor: auto;
  pointer-events: none
}

.swiper-button-prev,
.swiper-container-rtl .swiper-button-next {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,%3Csvg%20xmlns%3D'http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg'%20viewBox%3D'0%200%2027%2044'%3E%3Cpath%20d%3D'M0%2C22L22%2C0l2.1%2C2.1L4.2%2C22l19.9%2C19.9L22%2C44L0%2C22L0%2C22L0%2C22z'%20fill%3D'%23007aff'%2F%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E");
  left: 10px;
  right: auto
}

.swiper-button-prev.swiper-button-black,
.swiper-container-rtl .swiper-button-next.swiper-button-black {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,%3Csvg%20xmlns%3D'http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg'%20viewBox%3D'0%200%2027%2044'%3E%3Cpath%20d%3D'M0%2C22L22%2C0l2.1%2C2.1L4.2%2C22l19.9%2C19.9L22%2C44L0%2C22L0%2C22L0%2C22z'%20fill%3D'%23000000'%2F%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E")
}

.swiper-button-prev.swiper-button-white,
.swiper-container-rtl .swiper-button-next.swiper-button-white {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,%3Csvg%20xmlns%3D'http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg'%20viewBox%3D'0%200%2027%2044'%3E%3Cpath%20d%3D'M0%2C22L22%2C0l2.1%2C2.1L4.2%2C22l19.9%2C19.9L22%2C44L0%2C22L0%2C22L0%2C22z'%20fill%3D'%23ffffff'%2F%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E")
}

.swiper-button-next,
.swiper-container-rtl .swiper-button-prev {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,%3Csvg%20xmlns%3D'http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg'%20viewBox%3D'0%200%2027%2044'%3E%3Cpath%20d%3D'M27%2C22L27%2C22L5%2C44l-2.1-2.1L22.8%2C22L2.9%2C2.1L5%2C0L27%2C22L27%2C22z'%20fill%3D'%23007aff'%2F%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E");
  right: 10px;
  left: auto
}

.swiper-button-next.swiper-button-black,
.swiper-container-rtl .swiper-button-prev.swiper-button-black {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,%3Csvg%20xmlns%3D'http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg'%20viewBox%3D'0%200%2027%2044'%3E%3Cpath%20d%3D'M27%2C22L27%2C22L5%2C44l-2.1-2.1L22.8%2C22L2.9%2C2.1L5%2C0L27%2C22L27%2C22z'%20fill%3D'%23000000'%2F%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E")
}

.swiper-button-next.swiper-button-white,
.swiper-container-rtl .swiper-button-prev.swiper-button-white {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,%3Csvg%20xmlns%3D'http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg'%20viewBox%3D'0%200%2027%2044'%3E%3Cpath%20d%3D'M27%2C22L27%2C22L5%2C44l-2.1-2.1L22.8%2C22L2.9%2C2.1L5%2C0L27%2C22L27%2C22z'%20fill%3D'%23ffffff'%2F%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E")
}

.swiper-pagination {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-transition: .3s;
  transition: .3s;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  z-index: 10
}

.swiper-pagination.swiper-pagination-hidden {
  opacity: 0
}

.swiper-container-horizontal>.swiper-pagination-bullets,
.swiper-pagination-custom,
.swiper-pagination-fraction {
  bottom: 10px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%
}

.swiper-pagination-bullet {
  width: 8px;
  height: 8px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background: #000;
  opacity: .2
}

button.swiper-pagination-bullet {
  border: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-shadow: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  -ms-appearance: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none
}

.swiper-pagination-clickable .swiper-pagination-bullet {
  cursor: pointer
}

.swiper-pagination-white .swiper-pagination-bullet {
  background: #fff
}

.swiper-pagination-bullet-active {
  opacity: 1;
  background: #007aff
}

.swiper-pagination-white .swiper-pagination-bullet-active {
  background: #fff
}

.swiper-pagination-black .swiper-pagination-bullet-active {
  background: #000
}

.swiper-container-vertical>.swiper-pagination-bullets {
  right: 10px;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -50%, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, -50%, 0)
}

.swiper-container-vertical>.swiper-pagination-bullets .swiper-pagination-bullet {
  margin: 5px 0;
  display: block
}

.swiper-container-horizontal>.swiper-pagination-bullets .swiper-pagination-bullet {
  margin: 0 5px
}

.swiper-pagination-progress {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .25);
  position: absolute
}

.swiper-pagination-progress .swiper-pagination-progressbar {
  background: #007aff;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-transform: scale(0);
  transform: scale(0);
  -webkit-transform-origin: left top;
  transform-origin: left top
}

.swiper-container-rtl .swiper-pagination-progress .swiper-pagination-progressbar {
  -webkit-transform-origin: right top;
  transform-origin: right top
}

.swiper-container-horizontal>.swiper-pagination-progress {
  width: 100%;
  height: 4px;
  left: 0;
  top: 0
}

.swiper-container-vertical>.swiper-pagination-progress {
  width: 4px;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0
}

.swiper-pagination-progress.swiper-pagination-white {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .5)
}

.swiper-pagination-progress.swiper-pagination-white .swiper-pagination-progressbar {
  background: #fff
}

.swiper-pagination-progress.swiper-pagination-black .swiper-pagination-progressbar {
  background: #000
}

.swiper-container-3d {
  -webkit-perspective: 1200px;
  -o-perspective: 1200px;
  perspective: 1200px
}

.swiper-container-3d .swiper-cube-shadow,
.swiper-container-3d .swiper-slide,
.swiper-container-3d .swiper-slide-shadow-bottom,
.swiper-container-3d .swiper-slide-shadow-left,
.swiper-container-3d .swiper-slide-shadow-right,
.swiper-container-3d .swiper-slide-shadow-top,
.swiper-container-3d .swiper-wrapper {
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d
}

.swiper-container-3d .swiper-slide-shadow-bottom,
.swiper-container-3d .swiper-slide-shadow-left,
.swiper-container-3d .swiper-slide-shadow-right,
.swiper-container-3d .swiper-slide-shadow-top {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  pointer-events: none;
  z-index: 10;
}

.swiper-container-3d .swiper-slide-shadow-left {
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, from(rgba(0, 0, 0, .5)), to(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(right, rgba(0, 0, 0, .5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left, rgba(0, 0, 0, .5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0))
}

.swiper-container-3d .swiper-slide-shadow-right {
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, right top, left top, from(rgba(0, 0, 0, .5)), to(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0, 0, 0, .5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0, 0, 0, .5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0))
}

.swiper-container-3d .swiper-slide-shadow-top {
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(rgba(0, 0, 0, .5)), to(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, .5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top, rgba(0, 0, 0, .5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0))
}

.swiper-container-3d .swiper-slide-shadow-bottom {
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left bottom, left top, from(rgba(0, 0, 0, .5)), to(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, .5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, .5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0))
}

.swiper-container-coverflow .swiper-wrapper,
.swiper-container-flip .swiper-wrapper {
  -ms-perspective: 1200px
}

.swiper-container-cube,
.swiper-container-flip {
  overflow: visible
}

.swiper-container-cube .swiper-slide,
.swiper-container-flip .swiper-slide {
  pointer-events: none;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  z-index: 1
}

.swiper-container-cube .swiper-slide .swiper-slide,
.swiper-container-flip .swiper-slide .swiper-slide {
  pointer-events: none
}

.swiper-container-cube .swiper-slide-active,
.swiper-container-cube .swiper-slide-active .swiper-slide-active,
.swiper-container-flip .swiper-slide-active,
.swiper-container-flip .swiper-slide-active .swiper-slide-active {
  pointer-events: auto
}

.swiper-container-cube .swiper-slide-shadow-bottom,
.swiper-container-cube .swiper-slide-shadow-left,
.swiper-container-cube .swiper-slide-shadow-right,
.swiper-container-cube .swiper-slide-shadow-top,
.swiper-container-flip .swiper-slide-shadow-bottom,
.swiper-container-flip .swiper-slide-shadow-left,
.swiper-container-flip .swiper-slide-shadow-right,
.swiper-container-flip .swiper-slide-shadow-top {
  z-index: 0;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden
}

.swiper-container-cube .swiper-slide {
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%
}

.swiper-container-cube.swiper-container-rtl .swiper-slide {
  -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 0;
  transform-origin: 100% 0
}

.swiper-container-cube .swiper-slide-active,
.swiper-container-cube .swiper-slide-next,
.swiper-container-cube .swiper-slide-next+.swiper-slide,
.swiper-container-cube .swiper-slide-prev {
  pointer-events: auto;
  visibility: visible
}

.swiper-container-cube .swiper-cube-shadow {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #000;
  opacity: .6;
  -webkit-filter: blur(50px);
  filter: blur(50px);
  z-index: 0
}

.swiper-container-fade.swiper-container-free-mode .swiper-slide {
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
  transition-timing-function: ease-out
}

.swiper-container-fade .swiper-slide {
  pointer-events: none;
  -webkit-transition-property: opacity;
  transition-property: opacity
}

.swiper-container-fade .swiper-slide .swiper-slide {
  pointer-events: none
}

.swiper-container-fade .swiper-slide-active,
.swiper-container-fade .swiper-slide-active .swiper-slide-active {
  pointer-events: auto
}

.swiper-zoom-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center
}

.swiper-zoom-container>canvas,
.swiper-zoom-container>img,
.swiper-zoom-container>svg {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  -o-object-fit: contain;
  object-fit: contain
}

.swiper-scrollbar {
  border-radius: 10px;
  position: relative;
  -ms-touch-action: none;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .1)
}

.swiper-container-horizontal>.swiper-scrollbar {
  position: absolute;
  left: 1%;
  bottom: 3px;
  z-index: 50;
  height: 5px;
  width: 98%
}

.swiper-container-vertical>.swiper-scrollbar {
  position: absolute;
  right: 3px;
  top: 1%;
  z-index: 50;
  width: 5px;
  height: 98%
}

.swiper-scrollbar-drag {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  border-radius: 10px;
  left: 0;
  top: 0
}

.swiper-scrollbar-cursor-drag {
  cursor: move
}

.swiper-lazy-preloader {
  width: 42px;
  height: 42px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  margin-left: -21px;
  margin-top: -21px;
  z-index: 10;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50%;
  transform-origin: 50%;
  -webkit-animation: swiper-preloader-spin 1s steps(12, end) infinite;
  animation: swiper-preloader-spin 1s steps(12, end) infinite
}

.swiper-lazy-preloader:after {
  display: block;
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,%3Csvg%20viewBox%3D'0%200%20120%20120'%20xmlns%3D'http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg'%20xmlns%3Axlink%3D'http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2Fxlink'%3E%3Cdefs%3E%3Cline%20id%3D'l'%20x1%3D'60'%20x2%3D'60'%20y1%3D'7'%20y2%3D'27'%20stroke%3D'%236c6c6c'%20stroke-width%3D'11'%20stroke-linecap%3D'round'%2F%3E%3C%2Fdefs%3E%3Cg%3E%3Cuse%20xlink%3Ahref%3D'%23l'%20opacity%3D'.27'%2F%3E%3Cuse%20xlink%3Ahref%3D'%23l'%20opacity%3D'.27'%20transform%3D'rotate(30%2060%2C60)'%2F%3E%3Cuse%20xlink%3Ahref%3D'%23l'%20opacity%3D'.27'%20transform%3D'rotate(60%2060%2C60)'%2F%3E%3Cuse%20xlink%3Ahref%3D'%23l'%20opacity%3D'.27'%20transform%3D'rotate(90%2060%2C60)'%2F%3E%3Cuse%20xlink%3Ahref%3D'%23l'%20opacity%3D'.27'%20transform%3D'rotate(120%2060%2C60)'%2F%3E%3Cuse%20xlink%3Ahref%3D'%23l'%20opacity%3D'.27'%20transform%3D'rotate(150%2060%2C60)'%2F%3E%3Cuse%20xlink%3Ahref%3D'%23l'%20opacity%3D'.37'%20transform%3D'rotate(180%2060%2C60)'%2F%3E%3Cuse%20xlink%3Ahref%3D'%23l'%20opacity%3D'.46'%20transform%3D'rotate(210%2060%2C60)'%2F%3E%3Cuse%20xlink%3Ahref%3D'%23l'%20opacity%3D'.56'%20transform%3D'rotate(240%2060%2C60)'%2F%3E%3Cuse%20xlink%3Ahref%3D'%23l'%20opacity%3D'.66'%20transform%3D'rotate(270%2060%2C60)'%2F%3E%3Cuse%20xlink%3Ahref%3D'%23l'%20opacity%3D'.75'%20transform%3D'rotate(300%2060%2C60)'%2F%3E%3Cuse%20xlink%3Ahref%3D'%23l'%20opacity%3D'.85'%20transform%3D'rotate(330%2060%2C60)'%2F%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E");
  background-position: 50%;
  background-size: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat
}

.swiper-lazy-preloader-white:after {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,%3Csvg%20viewBox%3D'0%200%20120%20120'%20xmlns%3D'http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg'%20xmlns%3Axlink%3D'http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2Fxlink'%3E%3Cdefs%3E%3Cline%20id%3D'l'%20x1%3D'60'%20x2%3D'60'%20y1%3D'7'%20y2%3D'27'%20stroke%3D'%23fff'%20stroke-width%3D'11'%20stroke-linecap%3D'round'%2F%3E%3C%2Fdefs%3E%3Cg%3E%3Cuse%20xlink%3Ahref%3D'%23l'%20opacity%3D'.27'%2F%3E%3Cuse%20xlink%3Ahref%3D'%23l'%20opacity%3D'.27'%20transform%3D'rotate(30%2060%2C60)'%2F%3E%3Cuse%20xlink%3Ahref%3D'%23l'%20opacity%3D'.27'%20transform%3D'rotate(60%2060%2C60)'%2F%3E%3Cuse%20xlink%3Ahref%3D'%23l'%20opacity%3D'.27'%20transform%3D'rotate(90%2060%2C60)'%2F%3E%3Cuse%20xlink%3Ahref%3D'%23l'%20opacity%3D'.27'%20transform%3D'rotate(120%2060%2C60)'%2F%3E%3Cuse%20xlink%3Ahref%3D'%23l'%20opacity%3D'.27'%20transform%3D'rotate(150%2060%2C60)'%2F%3E%3Cuse%20xlink%3Ahref%3D'%23l'%20opacity%3D'.37'%20transform%3D'rotate(180%2060%2C60)'%2F%3E%3Cuse%20xlink%3Ahref%3D'%23l'%20opacity%3D'.46'%20transform%3D'rotate(210%2060%2C60)'%2F%3E%3Cuse%20xlink%3Ahref%3D'%23l'%20opacity%3D'.56'%20transform%3D'rotate(240%2060%2C60)'%2F%3E%3Cuse%20xlink%3Ahref%3D'%23l'%20opacity%3D'.66'%20transform%3D'rotate(270%2060%2C60)'%2F%3E%3Cuse%20xlink%3Ahref%3D'%23l'%20opacity%3D'.75'%20transform%3D'rotate(300%2060%2C60)'%2F%3E%3Cuse%20xlink%3Ahref%3D'%23l'%20opacity%3D'.85'%20transform%3D'rotate(330%2060%2C60)'%2F%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E")
}

@-webkit-keyframes swiper-preloader-spin {
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg)
  }
}

@keyframes swiper-preloader-spin {
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg)
  }
}

.swiper-container.one {
  padding-top: 40px;
  text-align: center;
}

.swiper-container.one .swiper-slide {
  padding: 0 43px;
}

.swiper-container {
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 60px;
}

.slider-image {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

.swiper-slide img {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 100%;
}

.swiper-slide {
  height: auto;
  padding: 0 15px;
}

.two .swiper-slide {
  width: 300px;
}

.swiper-slide img {
  box-shadow: 0 10px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}

.swiper-slide .slider-image .preview-icon {
  z-index: -1;
  width: calc(100% - 30px);
}

.swiper-slide.swiper-slide-active .slider-image:hover .preview-icon {
  opacity: 1;
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
  z-index: 1;
}

.swiper-container-horizontal>.swiper-pagination-bullets,
.swiper-pagination-custom,
.swiper-pagination-fraction {
  bottom: 0;
}

.swiper-pagination-bullet {
  background: transparent none repeat scroll 0 0;
  border: 1px solid #ee0f6f;
  border-radius: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 10px;
  opacity: 1;
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
  width: 26px;
  -webkit-transition: 0.2s;
  transition: 0.2s;
}

.swiper-pagination-bullet-active {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #ee0f6f 0%, #f89482 100%) repeat scroll 0 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) linear-gradient(to right, #ee0f6f 0%, #f89482 100%) repeat scroll 0 0;
  border: medium none;
  height: 12px;
  opacity: 1;
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
  width: 12px;
}

.swiper-slide{
opacity: 0;
}
.swiper-slide-prev,
.swiper-slide-active,
.swiper-slide-next{
opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.css" />

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/3.4.1/js/swiper.min.js"></script>

<div class="swiper-container two">
  <div class="swiper-wrapper">
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <div class="slider-image">
        <img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=0B_koKn2rKOkLRml1b3B6eXVqQ2s" alt="slide 1">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <div class="slider-image">
        <img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=0B_koKn2rKOkLWTdaX3J5b1VueDg" alt="slide 2">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <div class="slider-image">
        <img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=0B_koKn2rKOkLVUpEems2ZXpHYVk" alt="slide 3">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <div class="slider-image">
        <img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=0B_koKn2rKOkLNXBIcEdOUFVIWmM" alt="slide 4">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <div class="slider-image">
        <img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=0B_koKn2rKOkLWTdaX3J5b1VueDg" alt="slide 5">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <div class="slider-image">
        <img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=0B_koKn2rKOkLWTdaX3J5b1VueDg" alt="slide 5">
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Add Pagination -->
  </div>
  <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
</div>
```